# Evaluating Logic Circuits

Tags: logic

[image]

Is the boolean expression for this circuit: ((NOT A AND NOT C AND B) AND (B AND A AND C))?

I need to find that out before I start the truth tables. That'd be the easiest way to evaluate the circuit for each question right?

I am not sure how I would do these problems.

Comment: What circuit do you mean?

Comment: Someone just edited my post, it should be available now

Comment: To me it seems slightly easier to just trace given inputs through the circuit, rather then converting to the boolean expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The symbol on the right is an OR, the rest of your code is correct.

Comment: So: ((NOT A AND NOT C AND B) OR (B AND A AND C))

Comment: Looks Ok to me.

Comment: "What is the logic expression for the diagram" That means what I just put, ((NOT A AND NOT C AND B) OR (B AND A AND C)), right?

Comment: Yes, I got that, changing the central AND into an OR fixed it.

Comment: Also this simplifies to $\textsf{ B and ((not A and not C) or (A and C)) }$ which is: $\textsf{ B and (A iff C) }$ @Hello